# uwsgi and "No module named django.core.wsgi"

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

On a fairly vanilla FreeBSD system without virtualenv, I'm having trouble getting uwsgi to work with Django.

Attempting to run generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myapp/wsgi.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

myapp/wsgi.py is not modified from stock. My ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /usr/local/www
module = myapp.wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 1
socket = /var/run/django.sock
pidfile = /var/run/django.pid
vacuum = true
uid = www
gid = www
enable-threads = true
```

My research only shows problems related to virtualenv which I'm not using. Any ideas what could be going on? Using Python 3.4 and latest uwsgi from ports. Running `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application` in a Python shell yields no errors.

Comment: I also have the issue on a Ubuntu 14.04 that have been dist-upgraded multiple times. I don't know the cause, but a temporary solution is to manually add the pip directory to the python path. In the ini file, you can add `pythonpath = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, or wherever the pip directory is.